# Django can't connect to Postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm working on my first ever Django project. I've Create a Postgresql Database on a host(which my project is already on that host) which is accessible on public network too .I can connect to the database on my local computer so the database is created. But in production I'm trying to migrate to the database but I got the `FATAL:  database "postgre" does no t exist`
I tried to connect it on my local with public network host and port but still got the same error.
here is my db code :

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': config('ENGINGE', default='django.db.backends.postgresql'),
       'NAME': config('NAME', default='postgre'),
       'USER': config('USER', default='postgre'),
       'PASSWORD': config('PASSWORD', default='postgre'),
       'HOST': config('HOST', default='postgre'),
       'PORT': config('PORT', default='5432'),
   }
}
```

I'm passing the variables with .env.
Also I tried to connect with `dj-database-url` like this :

```
DATABASES = DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config('DATABASE_URL')
```

And in both cases I've got the same error.
Does anyone got any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: How do you pass `.env` file to the application?

Comment: @HarunYilmaz with ```django-decouple``` but I don't think the problem is that because it pass ```DEBUG``` and ```SECRET_KEY``` too and I don't get error on them.

Comment: Can you try `os.getenv('ENGINE','django.db.backends.postgresql')` instead of `config`? And for the other variables of course

Comment: @HarunYilmaz I tried it but its not working too

Comment: Then that means that you're not correctly passing the env variables

Comment: Or it might be a typo in `ENGINGE`. Can you verify you have the variable passed as `ENGINGE` or `ENGINE`?

Comment: @HarunYilmaz yes the variables are passing correctly because the error says  the database name```FATAL:  database "database-name" does not exist``` I also check typos and all seems alright

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 issues here:

1. Check if the variables are actually getting accessed and cross verify the default values provided.
2. It is likely you might not have run the command to apply the initial database migrations.
   Your configuration should look like this:

   ```
   'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
      'NAME': config('NAME', default='postgre'),
      'USER': config('USER', default='postgre'),
      'PASSWORD': config('PASSWORD', default='postgre'),
      'HOST': config('HOST', default='postgre'),
      'PORT': config('PORT', default='5432'),
   }
   ```

You can achieve this by running the following commands:

```
    python manage.py makemigrations
    python manage.py migrate
```

Then you can run the server as usual with:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: You cannot apply the migrations when you have an error like `FATAL:  database "postgre" does not exist`

Comment: @AryanRajaput yes I've checked and all the variables are passed correctly and for the second one ```makemigrations``` says there is no change and for ```migrate``` I've got the ```FATAL:  database "postgre" does not exist``` error

Comment: @Alien One more observation is that the ENGINE config can be passed statically. I have made the edit for the same. Can you try that?

Comment: @AryanRajaput I try that too but still the same error

Comment: @Alien Can you ensure that the PostgreSQL server is running? Also the cross verify the database name, password using pgadmin or psql command line.

Comment: @AryanRajaput yes the servers is running . I can connect to the database with psql command line but django won't recognize it.